# How use freemarker to send email with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

How can i use freemarker to send email with spring-boot? i look in spring-boot examples and dont find anything

I want to generate the body of email with my template

tks

Comment: I also looking for the same almost, but i want send mail after complete of Registration , a mail has to send to his/her mail id with template

Answer (score 12):

There is a "Configuration" Object that you can get as bean:

Here is the code:

```
package your.package;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;

@Controller
public class MailTemplate {
    @Autowired
    Configuration configuration;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public @ResponseBody String test2() throws Exception {

        // prepare data
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("name", "Max Mustermann");

        // get template
        Template t = configuration.getTemplate("test.html");

        String readyParsedTemplate = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils
                .processTemplateIntoString(t, data);

        // do what ever you want to do with html...

        // just for testing:
        return readyParsedTemplate;

    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you expect the templates to change at runtime, you should inject the "Template" singleton directly, not the "Configuration" object.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should define Email content using Freemarker Template, for example

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body>
    <p>Dear ${firstName} ${lastName},</p>
    <p>Sending Email using Spring Boot with <b>FreeMarker template !!!</b></p>
    <p>Thanks</p>
    <p>${signature}</p>
    <p>${location}</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Next, creating email service which process email template and returns mine message object, such as

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateUtils;
import com.javabycode.model.Mail;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;

@Service
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfig;


    public void sendEmail(Mail mail) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        // Using a subfolder such as /templates here
        freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates");

        Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("email-template.ftl");
        String text = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, mail.getModel());

        helper.setTo(mail.getMailTo());
        helper.setText(text, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getMailSubject());

        sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

However, It is not suitable to share full working example here. You can refer to the completed tutorial [Spring Boot Freemarker Email Template](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-freemarker-email-template.html)

Hope this helps!